# Can I have multiple tz addresses for an unique baking node?

Tags: baking, node, account, address

Is it possible to have multiple addresses compouning an unique baking node? If so, how to migrate from the current public address, moving all delegators, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple addresses baking on the same node/baker, but it is not possible to have them act as a single baker. It it also not possible to move delegators to a new address, they would have to do it themselves.

You can always move your own funds to another address, or multiple addresses, but you would just end up spreading your rolls on multiple bakers.

Comment: What about multisig addresses?

Comment: I'm not up to date on multi-sig support in Tezos. I'm not sure how that would make a difference though, it's still 1 address that represent the baker - only difference is that it would require multiple parties to sign any transaction to move funds or vote etc.